# Safe way to merge several branches

Tags: git, merge, version-control

We have several branches and I want to make sure I don't do anything stupid.

Branch 1 has: Commit A + Commit B

Branch 2 Has: Commit A + Commit C (which is work continued from Commit A) + Commit D

Branch 3 is a new branch

Branch 4 (master)

I need to merge commit A and part of commit C into the master branch as there has been delays with the work related to commit D so now my client want the feature from commit C released on a separate schedule from commit D.

I thought about creating a pull request to branch 3 with a cherry-pick on commit A and commit C. However, I can't do this because commit C includes a remaster, some merge conflict fixes, and the relevant additional code.

Questinos:

1. If I just copy and paste the relevant code and make a PR into Branch 3 will I have issues later on when Branch 1, Branch 2, and Branch 3 are all eventually merged into master?
2. Is git smart enough to pick up on copy and pastes if I don't cherry-pick commits or will there be code duplication problems on the master branch when all the branches are eventually merged?

I have to use Branch 3 for raising a merge to release pull request and I'm not allowed to touch on Branch 1. There's a separate team working on that.

Comment: "However, I can't do this because commit C includes a remaster, some merge conflict fixes, and the relevant additional code." So is Commit C a merge commit with another branch? AND you included code changes in that merge conflict? Don't do this. Merge commits should only include the merge and any resolutions to conflicts. Make new commits with any other changes on top of that merge.

Comment: Or is Commit C a squashed commit from a PR from another branch? If you still have that branch available, use its history to get the "part of commit c" that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my advice:

1. Make a new branch: `feature_commit_c` at `master` (looks like this is `branch 3`)
2. Merge commit C (don't need a branch there, use the hash) into `feature_commit_c` to make your first commit in this branch.
3. Make any changes necessary related to "only part of commit C". Test, prep, make any other updates and new commits.
4. Create a PR from new branch to `master`
5. Complete PR review as/if required by team
6. Merge to `master`

This should be the cleanest. I always start new branches from where they will merge back into, and side-merge from other branches if I need their existing changes. There are some issues avoided that way, and shows your intent much more cleanly, but that part is up to you.

---

### Note on your other questions

Git just looks at the text, it doesn't know where it came from. If it's the same, then the diff will show no difference.  So, how you manage making the partial changes from C (whether you tack them onto A with copy/paste or selective reset of files from commit C) is up to you.

After you merge A and get your partial C changes complete, a diff between the a-c-d branch and your new branch should just be the rest of C and all of D.

You can always have conflicts on master, that's just part of the deal. But that should only happen in binary files that change or files/line combos that change in both branches, after ignoring the common stuff (from the base commit + anything cherry-picked in full).

Answer (score 0):

> I need to merge commit A and part of commit C

Commits are the fundamental unit of git. You cannot do anything with "part" of a commit, including merging. You will need to edit your history to break Commit C into smaller parts so you can pick what goes in other branches. You split the with `git rebase -i` and then basically undoing Commit C and creating new commits C1, C2, etc with the smaller pieces you want.

In the future, I suggest that you create a new branch for each feature. You can create smaller commits on this branch as you work on the feature. I suggest making small, cohesive commits as you work. Then when the feature is finished, merged it into `master` or some other "trunk" branch. Don't just commit an entire large feature as a single commit.

> If I just copy and paste the relevant code and make a PR into Branch 3 will I have issues later on when Branch 1, Branch 2, and Branch 3 are all eventually merged into master?

If you copy/paste the code at the exact same location in the file, then most likely future merges will have conflicts. These should be pretty easy to resolve as long as there are no other changes to these lines on either branch.